# Is "LIKE %%" identical to "LIKE %"?

Tags: mysql, sql

Are there any differences between the following two queries:

`SELECT name from Roster WHERE id LIKE %`

and:

`SELECT name from Roster WHERE id LIKE %%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent.  The `%` wildcard matches zero or more characters.  So both of these check that `id` is not `NULL`.

Note that the `like` pattern needs to be a string.  So, both your example would generate syntax errors.  You want:

```
where id like '%'
where id like '%%'
```

Also, if `id` is a number, then you should not be using a string operation on it -- under most circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
Here you will get clarification :

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.